# How can I integrate Dropzone.js in Ruby on Rails 7.1.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dropzone.js

I'm attempting to integrate dropzone.js in Rail version 7.1.2, but JavaScript does not work. There appears to be a problem with importing node modules in the most recent version of Rails, so I manually added the CSS styles for the dropzone in the stylesheets' folder; however, this approach does not work for JavaScript.  Another thing I observed is that the Dropzone js cdn works, but I need to load the JavaScript locally.

**This is my application.js file**

```js
// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "./controllers"


import jquery from "jquery"

//= require dropzone

window.jQuery = jquery
window.$ = jquery



window.Dropzone = require(dropzone)


// import "trix"
// import "@rails/actiontext/"
```

Comment: try `import dropzone from "dropzone"` instead of a require

Comment: @MikeSzyndel I tried  ```js import dropzone from "dropzone``` but it didn't work; nevertheless, I found a workaround, I inserted the content of dropzone.js directly in the .html.erb file.

Comment: it depends on what you're using for your javascript: `importmap-rails` or `jsbundling-rails`

Comment: @Alex I am using jsbundling-rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
$ yarn add dropzone
```

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

import Dropzone from "dropzone";

document.addEventListener("turbo:load", function(event) {
  let myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone");
  myDropzone.on("addedfile", file => {
    console.log(`File added: ${file.name}`);
  });
})
```

```html
<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.css" type="text/css" />
```

```rb
# _form.html.erb

<%= form_with url: "/", class: :dropzone do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :img %>
<% end %>
```